# How to implement a filter associated to a specific wavelet

Tags: filter-design, wavelet, butterworth

I am working on ECG signals, to eventually extract features in order to detect an arrhythmia and classify it.
I am using Discrete Wavelet Transform with biorthogonal wavelet bior6.8
During my research, I came to know that wavelet transform is the convolution of the input processed signal with the daughter wavelets to get approximation and detail

$$X(a,b)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi\left( \frac{t-b}{a}\right)x(t)dt $$
where $a$ is scaling and $b$ is time.

I can't find the expression of the mother wavelet anywhere also when it came to practice DWT is usually presented as a filter bank of high pass and low pass filter 
The question is what is the difference between the different wavelets if it is always presented as a bank of filters [image: filter bank]

In my work, I used these two Butterworth high pass and low pass filters, but I still can't explain my choice, I read that Butterworth is the most used in signal processing and that it optimizes the frequency response in the passband, getting as much as you can from the wanted frequency 
Still, I have no arguments why I shouldn't use any others and not sure whether it is the correct way to implement bior 6.8 wavelet as I do not know any other way to implement wavelets and I would implement Daubechies or any other the same which do not make sense

```
from scipy.signal import filtfilt , butter

def butter_highpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='high', analog=False)
    return b, a

def butter_highpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_highpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data,padlen=0)
    return y
```

---

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    return b, a

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y
```

So basically and to resume, the question is what is the difference between wavelet transforms and how can we value that during implementation and then, the use of BF in this type of wavelet is it correct?

NB: the image inserted is from Wikipedia

Comment: So what is the question / problem?

Comment: I just edited the question , I want to know the difference between waveets in implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral formula is the continuous wavelet transform, where you indeed convolve the data with a (mother) wavelet at all locations and scales. It is, by essence, redundant, and very mild conditions are required from continuous wavelet shapes to have both analysis and synthesis, and many shapes exist in analytic form.

If you want to discretize the above scheme in a critical way, ie to convert $N$ samples of a signal into $N$ coefficients, then you reach the realm of the discrete wavelet transform. Here, quite a limited choice of admissible wavelets exists (compared to the continuous case). And there, most continuous wavelets don't fit in the [frame (pun intended)](http://cas.ensmp.fr/~chaplais/wavetour_presentation/frames/Wavelet_Frames.html). In other words, they cannot be discretized perfectly. The implementation technique was reversed: it was shown that the DWT could be implemented as the filter bank you mention. And from wavelet properties, filters properties where designed. Then, given a specific pair of admissible filters, wavelets are obtained through an iterative process, and generally, there is not closed form or formulae for such wavelets. If you are interested in more details, you can read [Filters and Wavelets for Dyadic Analysis](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/ERC14/Chapter7.pdf) by D. S. G. Pollock:

> Except in the polar cases of the Haar wavelet and the Shannon or sinc
>   function wavelet, an explicit functional form for the wavelet or the
>   scaling function is unlikely to be available. Nor is there, in most
>   practical applications, an indispensable requirement to represent of
>   these functions graphically

A whole DWT framework exists in Python: [PyWavelets - Wavelet Transforms in Python](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/). For instance, you can get [filter coefficients for the biorthogonal 6.8 wavelet](http://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/bior6.8/) [EDIT: on the page wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/bior6.8 under Coefficients, click "Show values" (or "Copy")].

Conversely, if you take any pair of low/high pass filters, it will not necessarily become a genuine DWT filter bank, because they don't have the necessary "wavelet type" properties.

So, basically, to implement a DWT the standard way, you should pick filter coefficients tabulated in the literature, or listed at the [PyWavelet property browser](http://wavelets.pybytes.com/).

Comment: Can you please share with me a paper where I can find the filter coefficients for analysis and synthesis of filter bank corresponding to bior6.8 ?

Comment: On the page http://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/bior6.8/ under Coefficients, click ""Show values" (or "Copy")

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned Butterworth filters for doing the wavelet analysis using `bior6.8`. If you want to perform the Discrete Wavelet Transform using some specific wavelet, then you must use its **Perfect Reconstruction Filter Bank**. Each wavelet function has its associated set of filter values for decomposition and reconstruction - they are calculated from the Mother and Daughter wavelet.

Since you were using Python, I am going to give you an example using [PyWavelets](http://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is as simple as creating a wavelet object and asking for the filter bank. Here is a plot of the filter values:

[image]

Since these are FIR filter coefficients, then we can calculate the amplitude response by taking the DFT of the coefficient values:

[image]

---

Values of filter coefficients:

```
dec_lo = [0.0,
 0.0019088317364812906,
 -0.0019142861290887667,
 -0.016990639867602342,
 0.01193456527972926,
 0.04973290349094079,
 -0.07726317316720414,
 -0.09405920349573646,
 0.4207962846098268,
 0.8259229974584023,
 0.4207962846098268,
 -0.09405920349573646,
 -0.07726317316720414,
 0.04973290349094079,
 0.01193456527972926,
 -0.016990639867602342,
 -0.0019142861290887667,
 0.0019088317364812906]

dec_hi = [-0.0,
 0.0,
 -0.0,
 0.014426282505624435,
 -0.014467504896790148,
 -0.07872200106262882,
 0.04036797903033992,
 0.41784910915027457,
 -0.7589077294536541,
 0.41784910915027457,
 0.04036797903033992,
 -0.07872200106262882,
 -0.014467504896790148,
 0.014426282505624435,
 -0.0,
 0.0,
 -0.0,
 0.0]

rec_lo = [0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.014426282505624435,
 0.014467504896790148,
 -0.07872200106262882,
 -0.04036797903033992,
 0.41784910915027457,
 0.7589077294536541,
 0.41784910915027457,
 -0.04036797903033992,
 -0.07872200106262882,
 0.014467504896790148,
 0.014426282505624435,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0]

rec_hi = [0.0,
 -0.0019088317364812906,
 -0.0019142861290887667,
 0.016990639867602342,
 0.01193456527972926,
 -0.04973290349094079,
 -0.07726317316720414,
 0.09405920349573646,
 0.4207962846098268,
 -0.8259229974584023,
 0.4207962846098268,
 0.09405920349573646,
 -0.07726317316720414,
 -0.04973290349094079,
 0.01193456527972926,
 0.016990639867602342,
 -0.0019142861290887667,
 -0.0019088317364812906]
```

---

A complementary code which might be useful for you to investigate other wavelets:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create wavelet and extract the filters
wavelet_name = 'bior6.8'
wavelet = pywt.Wavelet(wavelet_name)
dec_lo, dec_hi, rec_lo, rec_hi = wavelet.filter_bank

# Filter coefficients
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(221)
plt.stem(dec_lo)
plt.grid()
plt.title('{} low-pass decomposition filter'.format(wavelet_name))
plt.subplot(222)
plt.stem(dec_hi)
plt.grid()
plt.title('{} high-pass decomposition filter'.format(wavelet_name))
plt.subplot(223)
plt.stem(rec_lo)
plt.grid()
plt.title('{} low-pass reconstruction filter'.format(wavelet_name))
plt.subplot(224)
plt.stem(rec_hi)
plt.grid()
plt.title('{} high-pass reconstruction filter'.format(wavelet_name))

# Frequency responses
dec_lo_fr = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(dec_lo, 128))
dec_hi_fr = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(dec_hi, 128))
rec_lo_fr = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(rec_lo, 128))
rec_hi_fr = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(rec_hi, 128))

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(dec_lo_fr, label='Low-pass')
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(dec_hi_fr, label='High-pass')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.title('Frequency responses of {} decomposition filters'.format(wavelet_name))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(rec_lo_fr, label='Low-pass')
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(rec_hi_fr, label='High-pass')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.title('Frequency responses of {} reconstruction filters'.format(wavelet_name))

plt.show()
```

---

Regarding the actual filtering process you can either use `scipy.signal.lfilter` or `np.convolve` (`x` being the input signal):

```
y = lfilter(dec_lo, 1, x)
```

or

```
y = convolve(x, dec_lo)
```

I would suggest using PyWavelets to do all of that for you, instead of re-inventing the wheel. However, If you really want to implement a single level of DWT on your own then I second the `numpy` option. Here is a complete example:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 128)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)

# Perform manual DWT and decimate
cA = np.convolve(x, dec_lo)[1::2]
cD = np.convolve(x, dec_hi)[1::2]

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(cA)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Approximation coefficients')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(cD)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Detail coefficients')

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: So knowing the filters coefficients can I implement them ?

Comment: Do you need anything else? Everything is there. Is anything unclear to you?

Comment: Well I'm new to signal processing , so I'm not sure how to implement a filter knowing the coefficients

Comment: Please see my answer updated. You've got everything that you need to perform the analysis. Just don't use `filtfilt`.

Comment: how can I modify the cutoff frequency of these filters ? because I am implementing a filter bank where the cutoff frequency is devided by 2 from level to level ?

Comment: There is no need to modify anything. Just do the multi-level DWT as shown in the figure that you've attached. `cD` becomes an input to the next decomposition and so on.

Comment: @jojek I tend to believe that people want cutoff tunable DWT, which does not mix well with QMF and dyadic subsampling

Comment: @Abyr ... your question was of theoretical nature and I would say it was answered more than clear. Your follow up questions are neither related to wavelets nor signal processing. They are targeting programming, here I highly recommend you to read the help of these functions and google some tutorials. This way you will learn by far more ...

Comment: As lovely as filters are, what about the "lifting scheme"?
I guess it can only be used for "biorthogonal" wavelets and Haar is not one of them.